# Purpose of certain components

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

This problem asks you to create an algorithm to determine if a string has unique characters. I was looking through solutions and this seems to be the most simplistic one I can find, however there are still a few parts of this code I can't wrap my head around.

**boolean[] chars = new boolean[26];** 
what exactly is the coder doing? Do the 26 characters represent the 26 letters of the alphabet. I ask because when I fiddled around with the code and changed the value to 12, 15, 20 etc the program still gave correct output.

**if(chars[(int)c - 'A'])** What is the purpose of subtracting 'A' from the int c? I've seen this method of subtracting 'A' or 'a' in multiple solutions to this problems but I don't understand what purpose it serves.

```
public class PracticeProblems {

    public static void questionOne(String input) {
         boolean[] chars = new boolean[26];
         String upper = input.toUpperCase();

         for(int i = 0, n = upper.length(); i < n; i++){
             char c = upper.charAt(i);
             if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z'){
                 if(chars[(int)c - 'A']){
                     System.out.println("not unique");
                     return;
                 }
                chars[(int)c - 'A'] = true;
             }
         }
         System.out.println("unique");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        questionOne("bil");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, subtracting `c` from `'A'` is getting the index of the character i.e from 0 to 25, also, uppercase and lowercase matters, see http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes the `boolean[26]` represents 26 letters of (English) alphabet. If you change the size of the array it might still work depending on the input string and which characters it contains. You might just get lucky enough to have chars only in the range `[0,length]`.
2. as you can see first the string is being upperCased. Then you can notice that **A** is the first char in the <s>ASCII</s> Unicode/UTF-16 (see @Edit2 for clarification regarding Java char) char table for the English alphabet. By subtracting it from `c` you will map your chars from the Unicode values 65-90 into the char array range 0-25 (because A's 65 - 65 = 0 and Z's 90 - 65 = 25). Similarly if you lowerCase your input string you will substract `a`.

Here's the [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/). You have to know that each `char` in Java is represented with it (or well to be more precise character are represented with numbers by the computer), so in the end **A** for Java is **65**, **Z** is **90** so you can easily subtract them. The compiler will still complain that you are trying to access the `boolean` array value using a `char` for index, that's why you need the `(int)` cast (you know justjavathings.org).

Bare in mind that this solution will work only for the English alphabet, not other alphabets and/or other unicode characters. For that you either need a bigger array of change it into a `Map<Character, Boolean>`.

@Edit:

To answer the comment: you don't need to compare individual characters, the `boolean` array keeps track of whether given `char` has been seen in the string already or not. So first all values in the array will be set to `false` as you haven't seen any char yet. Then you check the first character of the string, you map it to a range 0-25 (let's call it idx) and set the array cell at `idx` with `true` as you've just seen this char. Then as you can see every iteration is first checking if the current char has been already seen:

```
if(chars[(int)c - 'A'])
```

If this value is set to true it means the given character is repeated.

@Edit2:

As Tom Blodget pointed out Java characters aren't only ASCII but (by default) UTF-16 (which basically is just a mapping from a number to a given character). This means there's much more of them but in the end what I've stated above still holds true as `'A'-'A' = 0` and then all following uppercase character are next to each other so `` 'B'-`A' = 1 `` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that the coder is trying to get a char array range. so how is he comparing the different chars to each other? He's iterating through the string but where is the data for each individual char going? I don't see a condition or comparison of the chars in the code.

Comment: A Java `char` is a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a codepoint. UTF-16 is not ASCII, but by design Unicode is a superset of ASCII characters and has the same codepoints for the common characters. Even so, referring to ASCII risks incorrect assumptions about Java `string` and `char`.

Comment: @TomBlodget that is a very fair point - this was a very bad shorthand on my side. Mind if I add it as an edit?

Comment: Thank you @MateuszDymczyk. Your comments are fantastic and have helped my understand the code. As a relatively new programmer, I really appreciate all your help.